# Recursion Stack Overflow C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I am new to C++ but thought that working on some project Euler problems would familiarize me with the language.

When attempting 
[Project Euler Problem 14: Longest Collatz sequence](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14)

I could not manage to get my C++ solution to work, but had no problem with my python solution...

```py
import time 
start = time.time()
memo = {1:1,2:2}
longest_chain, longest_starting_key = 2, 2

def rec(a):
    global longest_chain, longest_starting_key

    if a in memo.keys():
        return memo[a]    
    if a % 2 == 0:
        memo[a] = rec(a // 2) + 1
    else:
        memo[a] = rec(3 * a + 1) + 1
    if memo[a] > longest_chain:
        longest_chain = memo[a]
        longest_starting_key = a
    return memo[a]    

for i in range(1000000,3,-1): rec(i)

print("starting key", longest_starting_key , ": has length", longest_chain)
print((time.time() - start), "seconds")
```

and got

```
starting key 837799 has length 525
1.399820327758789 seconds
```

My C++ attempt... (that I thought was equivalent...)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
std::unordered_map<int, int> mem = { {1,1},{2,2} };
int longest_chain{ 2 }, best_starting_num{ 2 };

bool is_in(const int& i){
    auto search = mem.find(i);
    if(search == mem.end())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int f(int n){
    if(is_in(n))
        return mem[n];
    if(n % 2)
        mem[n] = f(3 * n + 1) + 1;
    else
        mem[n] = f(n / 2) + 1;
    if(mem[n] > longest_chain)
        longest_chain = mem[n];
    return mem[n];
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 3; i < 1000000; i++){
        f(i);
    }
    std::cout << longest_chain << std::endl;
}
```

When running this in Visual Studio in debug mode I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF75A64EB70 in
0014_longest)collatz_sequence_cpp.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow
(parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000DC81493FE0).
```

Someone told me that I should allocate on the heap using pointers, but have very limited experience with working with pointers...

The other thing I don't understand is... when I run it with 100'000 instead of 1'000'000 in the main body loop, it works but is very slow.

Comment: running it through vc++ debugger would help a lot. I think `mem` allocates new elements in the heap already.

Comment: When I run your C++ code on my system I get a result of 489 (not 525).  The Python and C++ versions are clearly not equivalent...

Comment: @Barry below provides a very good algorithmical answer, but there is also a coding error in your C++ version - you are doing map lookup twice whenever value is present, first to detect it's availability, second to actually get it. Not good.

Comment: It is worth doing a search of SO with the word [Collatz](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Collatz) for inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the invariant on the range of `n` that the Collatz sequence provides (mathematically), which your Python code satisfies but your C++ code doesn't? Hint to the hint: what are the last few values of `n` before your stack overflow actually occurs?

Comment: Ah, just what I was about to say, but the hint format is more in keeping with educational theme of the question's context. :)

Comment: I have been staring at it, but to no avail. I changed the main loop in python version to look like the C++ version (instead of counting down of goes from 1 to 999'999). changed the names so that they look more like each other... But I still cannot spot it.

Comment: @Quantifeye Start at `113383`. What are all the values of `n` that you call `f` with?